# Learning C, ran into issue with program to count characters and create a histogram

Tags: c

I've been starting to go through the process of learning C using the K&R book, and I ran into a exercise that has me attempt to take a character integer/counting program and get it to print out a histogram of the data, however while I was setting up the initial border for the histogram, I ran into a few issues.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c, i, nwhite, nother, chartlen,
        chartline;  /* create variables for getchar, index number, whitespace
                       count, other char count, and establish variables for use
                       creating histogram*/
    int ndigit[10]; /* create list */
    nwhite = nother = 0;
    chartlen = 10;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) /* iterate through each item */
        ndigit[i] = 0;       /* Set each item to its initial count, 0 */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c - '0']; /* ASCII hex code subtraction to result in
                                  appropriate decimal interpretation */
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            ++nwhite; /*checks for white space chars and then adds one to the
                         count */
        else
            ++nother; /* if neither a number or white space is found, add to
                         other count */
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d", nwhite, nother);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        if (ndigit[i] >
            chartlen) /*iterated through items from ndigit and check to see if
                         they're greater than the val of chartlen, if they are,
                         set chartlen to new value*/
            chartlen = ndigit[i];
        else
            continue;
    chartline = '-' * chartlen; /*create a line with the length of chartlen and
                                   then print it*/
    printf("%d\n", chartline);
}
```

The issue I've been running into starts right when I first use `chartlen`. With the section from

```
for (i=0; i<10; ++i) 
    if (ndigit[i] > chartlen )
```

and on, if it's commented out, the program runs fine. However, if the new section is left in "nother" seems to no longer count properly and prints values that seem arbitrary to me, and for some reason I can't figure out how to get the line for the histogram to print. What did I do wrong?

Comment: dude curly braced don't cost you anything

Comment: `chartline = '-'*chartlen; /*create a line with the length of chartlen and then print it*/` - NO. It is C, not Python.

Comment: to add to the comment above '-' is a char which is just like a 1 byte int... int * int is int... not a string of chartlen length... see  man memset and also malloc

Comment: Aside - with or without braces, `else continue;` is redundant as the last line in a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm exceedingly new to C, so curly braces are still something I need to remember. Also, I had looked up how to do this in C and "chartline = ' - '*chartlen" was what I ended up finding, which obviously doesn't work and is part of why I'm posting here

Comment: If you are looking for a maximum I suggest `chartlen = 10;` should be `chartlen = 0;` unless you never want the chart to be smaller than `10`.

Comment: `*` is an arithmetic operator and works for numbers only. To create a string - you need a space for it and a way to give a value to *each* character. you can use `memset` as suggested, but you have to take care of null-termination as well. Anyway, since you are working through the book, you will eventually come by the chapter about strings. It is not a trivial topic.

Comment: To print N `'-'`, code can use a loop `for(int i=0;i<N;i++) putchar('-');`

Comment: Posting a simple sample input and your output would add clarity to this post.  More useful than "no longer count properly".

Comment: yeah, chux, that's what I wound up doing a moment ago. I now just need to have it so it won't print less than 10 '-'. I thought the for loop I had set up above it would work but doesn't seem so

Comment: @Tpurdy Re-read [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159932/learning-c-ran-into-issue-with-program-to-count-characters-and-create-a-histogr#comment89303417_51159932) comment.

Comment: that's also true.Though, now that I've changed the final section to a for loop I no longer seem to be running into the issue.

Comment: A couple of comments have implicitly recognized this, but I want to make it explicit for the OP: chartline is declared as an int, so you shouldn't expect it to work as a string (ignoring the * operator issue). Use @chux's loop, and you don't need chartline at all.

Comment: Also please keep in mind that K&R's coding style is partly what it is to save space on the page and not clutter their examples with extraneous symbols while showing off some features. It's not exactly what most of us use today. There are some style habits that will help you avoid making common programming errors which the K&R book doesn't go into. One of them is avoid using declaration lists of the form `int c, i, nwhite, nother, ...` except maybe in cases where it makes sense, like `int x, y, z; // current location in universal coordinate frame`.

Comment: Using braces is mandatory at many companies.

Comment: @jwdonahue do you know of a better resource that I can look into after running through K&R?

Comment: Best I can offer is [a google search result](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=jM47W8_LMPDB0PEP0_abiAI&q=c+books+for+beginners&oq=C+books&gs_l=psy-ab.1.1.0l7j0i22i30k1l3.395.7024.0.10248.7.7.0.0.0.0.113.382.6j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.381...0i131k1.0.6_E3krAfE4A). All of my old reference material has been in boxes for over a decade. When you've been immersed in it for decades, you tend to just absorb stuff from exposure and experience.

Answer (score 0):

That `else continue;` is only confusing and `chartline = '-' * chartlen;` is just `chartline = 45 * chartlen;` is way more confusing. `printf("%d\n", chartline);` will just print a number: count of the most frequent number in the input multiplied by 45.
Find the height of the histogram and save it in `chartlen`, that's ok. Then for each column for each number print the char for histogram or space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int c;
    int i;
    int nwhite;
    int nother;
    int chartlen;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = 0;
    nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ndigit[i] = 0; 
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            ++ndigit[c - '0'];
        } else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            ++nwhite;
        } else {
            ++nother;
        }
    }

    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    }
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Histogram horizontally:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int j;
        printf("%2d ", i);
        for (j = 0; j < ndigit[i]; ++j) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Histogram vertically:\n");
    for (chartlen = 0, i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (chartlen < ndigit[i])
            chartlen = ndigit[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < chartlen; ++i) {
        int j;
        printf(" ");
        for (j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            if (ndigit[j] >= chartlen - i) {
                printf("*");
            } else {
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf(" ");
            /* or shorter: printf("%c ", ndigit[j] >= chartlen - i ? '*' : ' '); */
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf(" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9");
}
```

This program for the stdin:

`1234567899876352681543681254169234659237856427895653848467567846545438555463480000000329190328cfasvfhd adk af`

will print:

```
digits = 8 5 8 10 12 14 12 6 12 7, white space = 2, other = 1

Histogram horizontally:
 0 ********
 1 *****
 2 ********
 3 **********
 4 ************
 5 **************
 6 ************
 7 ******
 8 ************
 9 *******

Histogram vertically:
           *         
           *         
         * * *   *   
         * * *   *   
       * * * *   *   
       * * * *   *   
 *   * * * * *   *   
 *   * * * * *   * * 
 *   * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * 
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```